# How to display a specif document detail from firestore in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-test

I am trying to fetch a single document from firestore against the current logged in user. I need that piece of code if anyone can provide it.

Answer (score 1):

As writtenn in the [cloud firestore docs](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) this is how you can fetch a single document:

```
Firestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .document(userId)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      // use ds as a snapshot
    });
```

If you have the user id you can use it as the document name to load a specific document per user.

Comment: Firestore.instance.collection('Users').document("??").get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds){
      print(ds);
    });

Comment: I am using this and it gives Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot' as output

Comment: Does each user have a unique ID? You can use firebase auth to do it. https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth anonymous auth would be the simplest to implement.

Comment: I have the collection name "users" having 3 documents named as user-id. how I can fetch a specific one? Can I find the index of that particular document?

Comment: Try replacing the `"??"` with the users ID to get his document

Comment: Firebase auth can only give you 3 to 4  values but what if we want to fetch a document having other saved details

Comment: Firestore.instance.collection('Users').document('M2PaFs9izUh6QKWXjib0EurWISJ3').get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds){
      
    });  here it is. but how can i access the values inside that document?